# Problem solving Logical Equivalence Question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am working with Logical Equivalence problems as practice and im getting stuck on this question. Can somebody help?

Im trying to show that The LHS is equivalent to the RHS

(¬P ∧ ¬R) ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q ∧ ¬R) is equivalent to ¬R ∧ (Q ⇒ ¬(P ∧ ¬R))

I have tried this so far:

(¬(P ∨ R) ∨ (¬Q ∧ P ∧ ¬R))

¬(¬(P ∨ R) ∨ (¬Q ∧ P ∧ ¬R))

(P ∨ R) ∨ (Q ∧ ¬(P ∨ ¬R))

But im unsure how to carry on from here

Comment: Why not by truth tables?

Comment: @GitGud - I need to use Logical Equivalence - the laws

Comment: Add to the question the laws which you have available.

Comment: @GitGud - I can use any of the laws

Comment: Any of the laws from where?

Comment: Does it need to be a theorem or can it be a deductive proof?

Comment: @Ian - Im not sure what you mean? I need to show the left hand side is equivalent to Right hand side

Comment: There are two forms of proofs that can do this, one is a theorem and the other is a deductive proof with premises.  The theorem has no premises.

Comment: @Ian - I think it is Deductive

Comment: I am not sure if that is the main part of your difficulty but you are not applying the DeMorgan laws correctly, you're moving the not operator outside but not flipping the conjunction/disjunction operator

Comment: @benji - Oh sorry that was a mistake in typing - How can i go on after that?

Comment: Step 2 is wrong; you cannot negate the formula in step 1 ...

Answer (score 2):

**LHS** :

> $$(¬P ∧ ¬R) ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q ∧ ¬R) \equiv [¬P ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q)] ∧ ¬R \equiv$$

by *Distributivity*

> $$\equiv [(¬P ∨ P) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q)] ∧ ¬R \equiv$$

by *Distributivity* again; finally, due to : $T ∧ \alpha \equiv \alpha$, we have :

> > $$\equiv (¬P ∨ ¬Q) ∧ ¬R.$$

---

**RHS** :

> $$[¬R ∧ (Q \to ¬(P ∧ ¬R))] \equiv [¬R ∧ (¬Q ∨ ¬P ∨ R)] \equiv$$

by *Material Implication* and *De Morgan*; then by *Distributivity* again and : $F ∨ \alpha \equiv \alpha$, we have :

> $$\equiv (¬R ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (¬R ∧ ¬P) ∨ (¬R ∧ R) \equiv (¬R ∧ ¬Q) ∨ (¬R ∧ ¬P) \equiv$$

and finally, by *Distributivity* :

> $$\equiv ¬R ∧ (¬Q ∨ ¬P).$$

Comment: is there a way to carry on from where i left off at the top?

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that $(\neg P\land\neg R)\lor (P\land\neg Q\land\neg R)$ is equivalent to $\neg R\land(Q\to\neg(P\land\neg R))$. That is, you want to show that
$$
\underbrace{\neg R\land(Q\to\neg(P\land\neg R))}_{\text{LHS}} \equiv \underbrace{(\neg P\land\neg R)\lor (P\land\neg Q\land\neg R)}_{\text{RHS}}.
$$
To this end, consider the following chain of equivalences:
\begin{align}
\text{LHS} &\equiv \neg R\land(Q\to\neg(P\land\neg R))\tag{definition}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv \neg R\land[\neg Q\lor\neg(P\land\neg R)]\tag{$p\to q\equiv\neg p\lor q$}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv \neg R\land[\neg Q\lor(\neg P\lor R)]\tag{DeMorgan}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv \neg R\land[\neg Q\lor\neg P\lor R]\tag{associativity}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv (\neg R\land\neg Q)\lor(\neg R\land\neg P)\lor(\neg R\land R)\tag{distributivity}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv (\neg R\land\neg Q)\lor(\neg R\land\neg P)\tag{$\neg R\land R\equiv F$}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv \neg R\land(\neg Q\lor\neg P)\tag{distributivity}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv \neg R\land(\neg Q\lor\neg P)\land(\neg P\lor P)\tag{$\neg P\lor P\equiv T$}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv \neg R\land[(\neg Q\lor\neg P)\land(\neg P\lor P)]\tag{associativity}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv \neg R\land[\neg P\lor(\neg Q\land P)]\tag{distributivity}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv (\neg R\land\neg P)\lor[\neg R\land(\neg Q\land P)]\tag{distributivity}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv (\neg R\land\neg P)\lor[\neg R\land\neg Q\land P]\tag{associativity}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv (\neg P\land\neg R)\lor(P\land\neg Q\land\neg R)\tag{desired expression}\\[0.5em]
  &\equiv \text{RHS}\tag{definition}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, the simplest proof is to simplify both sides, showing that these lead to the same result.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$For the left hand side,

$$\calc
\tag{L} (\lnot P \land \lnot R) \;\lor\; (P \land \lnot Q \land \lnot R)
\op\equiv\hint{extract common conjunct $\;\lnot R\;$, i.e., $\;\land\;$ distributes over $\;\lor\;$}
(\lnot P \lor (P \land \lnot Q)) \;\land\; \lnot R
\op\equiv\hint{use negation of $\;\lnot P\;$ on right hand side of $\;\lor\;$}
(\lnot P \lor (\true \land \lnot Q)) \;\land\; \lnot R
\op\equiv\hint{simplify}
\tag{*} (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \;\land\; \lnot R
\endcalc$$

And for the right hand side:

$$\calc
\tag{R} \lnot R \;\land\; (Q \then \lnot(P \land \lnot R))
\op\equiv\hint{write $\;X \then Y\;$ as $\;\lnot X \lor Y\;$}
\lnot R \;\land\; (\lnot Q \lor \lnot(P \land \lnot R))
\op\equiv\hint{use $\;\lnot R\;$ on right hand side of leftmost $\;\land\;$}
\lnot R \;\land\; (\lnot Q \lor \lnot(P \land \true))
\op\equiv\hint{simplify}
\tag{**} \lnot R \;\land\; (\lnot Q \lor \lnot P)
\endcalc$$

Now $\ref{*}$ and $\ref{**}$ are equivalent, and therefore $\;\ref{L} \equiv \ref{R}\;$.